# River network from DEM

Tags: qgis

Anyone who know if there is a method of creating rivers network from digital elevation model in qgis as it does in contour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TauDEM: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/fr/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/taudem/index.html

It uses code from http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/index.html, which can be used also outside qgis